# How do I lock a MySQL DATABASE so that write/read/update/delete ..everything is locked?

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I want to lock everything--completely. Very simple.  **Just prevent things from changing!!**
Will this work?

```
use mydatabase;
flush tables with read lock;
```

...

```
unlock tables;
```

Edit: But, it has to be available for replication.

Comment: why do you want to do this? answering this question will help us find you the best solution for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't it be simpler to adjust the security for the user account accessing the database so that it only has read access?

Answer (score 2):

This closes all open tables and locks all tables for all databases with a read lock until you execute UNLOCK TABLES.

Comment: What does that mean...does it accomplish what I want?

Comment: maybe. clients that want to write will stall until the table is unlocked or they time out. in addition, any clients that want to read after a writer stalls will also stall. if you want all writes to error, you need to change the user permissions.

Comment: i agree = you should go with read only permissions for the username accessing the data. my suggestion works within the same transaction.